# Impish 21.10 system does not start fully after patching - systemd queued jobs

Tags: boot, systemd

I have an Impish (21.10) system which was patched and rebooted recently (via "unattended-upgrade"), but it will not fully boot up; systemd is stuck with 6 jobs in the "queued" state:

```
$ systemctl list-jobs
JOB UNIT                                 TYPE  STATE  
114 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting
1   graphical.target                     start waiting
13  setvtrgb.service                     start waiting
2   multi-user.target                    start waiting
147 system-getty.slice                   start waiting
174 plymouth-quit-wait.service           start running

6 jobs listed.
```

SSH login to the system works.

docker-ce 5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-hirsute is installed, and usually fails to correctly start its application at boot time. A simple "docker stop  && docker start " resolves that issue (the app does appear to be running correctly at this point).

Attempting to run 'systemctl restart ' for either of system-getty.slice or setvtrgb.service does not appear to do anything (command hangs > 1 minute, I generally break out with ctrl-c and move on to other commands).

Setting "systemctl disbable docker" and rebooting does not resolve the situation.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide what you did before the failed boot (esp. installing softwares), if you can remember.

Comment: It looks like something is stuck. Suggest you see if `journalctl -p3 -b0` reveals the culprit

Comment: RESOLVED.  Re: the questions above: 1) what we did before the failed boot? apt update && apt upgrade. 2) journalctl -p3 -b0 did help, it highlight some error messages coming from the 'fwupd' process repeatedly failing.  Updating the system again some time later resulted in the 'fwupd' errors stopping, and system reboot started working again.

Comment: Keep in mind that Ubuntu 21.10 goes EOL July 14, 2022, at which time your system will no longer receive security updates if you continue to use 21.10. In most circumstances, it is highly recommended that you back up your data and upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 before that date. (Admittedly, I am guilty of still running 21.10 on an old laptop I use daily, I probably should take my own advice here...)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED.

Re: the questions above:

1. what we did before the failed boot? apt update && apt upgrade.
2. journalctl -p3 -b0 did help, it highlighted some error messages coming from the 'fwupd' process repeatedly failing. Updating the system again some time later resulted in the 'fwupd' errors stopping, and system reboot started working again.